# injective modules and divisible modules

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, injective-modules

The following result is basic ( P.J.Hilton, U.Stammabach, a course in homological algebra ).

Let $A$ be a principal ideal domain. Then a $A$ module is injective iff it is divisible.

Now if the condition is "Let $A$ be a domain", does the result hold ?
I think that it is probably wrong. Can anyone give me a counterexample?

Comment: The classical example is $\mathrm{Frac}(A)/A$. It's divisible, but, as far I remember, usually not injective.

Comment: Corollary 3.24 In Lam's GTM book: https://books.google.fr/books?id=r9VoYbk-8c4C&pg=PA71&lpg=PA71&dq=non-injective+divisible+module&source=bl&ots=Gm8p-xSFrW&sig=Y-cd4-QspbpddZD-B7QOIAhJexo&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiF8e7TwNTPAhVG4WMKHVhQDsw4ChDoAQgpMAI#v=onepage&q=non-injective%20divisible%20module&f=false: all divisible $A$-modules are injective iff $A$ is Dedekind.

Comment: What is your definition of "divisible" for a module over an arbitrary ring? (There seem to be different variants in use.)

Comment: A $A$-module $D$ is divisible if for every $d$ in $D$ and every nonzero $a$ in $A$ there exists $c$ in $D$ such that $ac=d$.@ Fred Rohrer

Comment: This seems to be a rather strange notion of divisibility. For example, if your ring is not reduced, then the zero module is the only divisible module. I suggest you consider only non-zerodivisors, or (and probably better) you take the definition given in Lam's book mentioned by Yves. (The @-notification works only if there is no space right after the @.)

Comment: Oh, I just realised that I misread the question. You do not want to omit "domain", but only "principal". Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ be a domain.  Then an $A$-torsion-free $A$-module is injective if and only if it is divisible.  This is well-known.  As mentioned in one of the comments, an arbitrary divisible $A$-module is injective if and only if $A$ is a Dedekind domain.

Comment: Does this also hold in the graded case? If $A$ is a graded domain and $M$ a graded torsion free module, is $M$ injective in the graded modules iff $M$ is graded divisible? Does this imply that $k[x,x^{-1}]$ is graded injective?